# Deserialized JSON with Invalid Ids are ignored silently

Tags: apex, validation, update, deserialize, record

Below String has invalid Id for Lookup(Contact). But it's deserialized without an error, which I hope is okay. My concern is Update DML is run without any error and ignoring the invalid value instead of throwing an error.

[image]

```
String jsonStr = '[{"attributes":{"type":"Case_Business_Contact__c"},'+
    '"Role__c":"Director","Id":"a0C9t00000oP9o8EAC","Contact__c":"invalid"}]';

List<Case_Business_Contact__c> cbs = 
    (List<Case_Business_Contact__c>)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr,
                                                     List<Case_Business_Contact__c>.class);

update cbs;

System.debug('cbs>> '+cbs[0]);
```

Is this a Salesforce normal behavior? I wonder if we need to manually validate these lookups running additional queries to see if Contact, etc. exists?

Successful execution debug log shows as below.
[image]

Comment: What is saved to your db? If you re-query and print that?

Comment: @zaitsman It's the same value which it had before - it was not empty. And No exceptions for invalid Id, silent successful dml instead.

Comment: That looks like a bug. It should be reported to Salesforce or something. But this is something of a question: why are your clients randomly returning non-Id values in Id fields? It's probably better to just do the DML and report any errors.

Comment: @sfdcfox This was a Test case actually with a Valid Id value which is not a Contact Id. For my POC I used an obviious Invalid string to make it fail. It's supposed to fail, instead ignored.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama Oh, no, you need to do a query or DML in order to validate an ID. After all, they're just sequential numbers. And an Id valid for one user might not be for another, sharing rules and all that.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox , Also found this is a Master-Detail (rather than a simple lookup)  which has Reparentable setting OFF. Advised testing team to fix the Test case accordingly. Not 100% satisfied on test case or the outcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this is a Master-Detail field which is set to Reparentable OFF. It cannot be updated. As a workaround to prompt the exception, just assigned the field value to the same if it's not empty.